# Citation and question marks works fine in title in a node, but not in a view

Tags: 7, views

I have to be able to use citation and question marks in a node title. It seems to work fine in the node and in the content manager, but the view that lists the nodes does not show it correctly.

" becomes `&quot;`
& becomes `&amp;`

Why does it not work in views, and how do I resolve the issue?

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: I just verified it on Drupal 7 instance. It works perfectly in views out of the box !! Not sure what kind of customization's are done in your instance !

Comment: Right? It is odd. But when I edit the view that's used, it works in the preview.

Comment: Your title is sanitized twice.
Is the title being outputted as its own field in Views, or are you adding it to another field through a token?

Comment: It is its own field. No token.

Comment: Oh, come on. WHy is this not working?